# Encoding and decoding information according the endian

Tags: endianness

I'm implementing the application layer of a communication protocol. I have to decode and encode byte arrays according several message specifications. The protocol specified little-endian for the fields so I extrapolated to the whole array.
Imagin that a message is specified as follows:

```
byte 0: 1 byte natural
byte 1..2: 2 bytes natural
byte 3..22: 20 bytes text according latin-1
byte 23..42: 20 bytes text according latin-1

So if I fill the information:
byte 0: 0x01
byte 1..2: 0x0001
byte 3..22: "This is an example  "
byte 23..42: "This is an example  "
```

I was encoding that as follows:

20 20 65 6C 70 6D 61 78 65 20 6E 61 20 73 69 20 73 69 68 54 20 20 65 6C 70 6D 61 78 65 20 6E 61 20 73 69 20 73 69 68 54 01 00 01

The specifiers have changed some requirements wording and now sounds to big-endian. I've asked them to provide the example above and they sent me the buffer below, so I'm totally confused, because for me this is big endian, I don't see byte swapping for fields with more than one byte, and everything is interpreted as a human-readable way from left-to-right:

01 00 01 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 6E 20 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 20 20 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 6E 20 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 20 20

They sent me too the discussion about byte ordering, and all the discussion is about little-endian. That clashes with the buffer above, as I clearly see that is interpreted in big-endian and according the new requirements wording.

What's your opinion?